# Poisson generalized linear mixed models (GLMMs): hard decision between lme4 and glmmADMB

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Random coefficient Poisson models are rather difficult to fit, there tends to be some variability in parameter estimates between lme4 and glmmADMB. But in my case:

```
# Packages
library(lme4)
library(glmmADMB)

#Open my dataset

myds<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_glmm_dataset.csv")
str(myds)

# 'data.frame': 526 obs. of  10 variables:
#  $ Bioma      : chr  "Pampa" "Pampa" "Pampa" "Pampa" ...
#  $ estacao    : chr  "verao" "verao" "verao" "verao" ...
#  $ ciclo      : chr  "1°" "1°" "1°" "1°" ...
#  $ Hour       : int  22 23 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
#  $ anthill    : num  23.5 23.5 23.5 23.5 23.5 ...
#  $ formigueiro: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ ladenant   : int  34 39 29 25 20 31 16 28 21 12 ...
#  $ unladen    : int  271 258 298 317 316 253 185 182 116 165 ...
#  $ UR         : num  65.7 69 71.3 75.8 78.1 ...
#  $ temp       : num  24.3 24.3 24 23.7 23.1 ...
```

I have a number of insects (`ladenant`) in the function of biome(`Bioma`), temperature (`temp`) and humidity(`UR`), but `formiguieros` is pseudoreplication. Then I try to model the relationship using lme4 and glmmADMB.

First I try lme4:

```
 m.laden.1  <- glmer(ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp,2) + UR + (1 | formigueiro), data = DataBase, family = poisson(link = "log"))
    summary(m.laden.1)
    # Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
    #  Family: poisson  ( log )
    # Formula: ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp, 2) + UR + (1 | formigueiro)
    #    Data: DataBase
    
    #      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    #  21585.9  21615.8 -10786.0  21571.9      519 
    
    # Scaled residuals: 
    #     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    # -10.607  -4.245  -1.976   2.906  38.242 
    
    # Random effects:
    #  Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
    #  formigueiro (Intercept) 0.02049  0.1432  
    # Number of obs: 526, groups:  formigueiro, 5
    
    # Fixed effects:
    #                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    # (Intercept)      0.7379495  0.0976701   7.556 4.17e-14 ***
    # BiomaTransition  1.3978383  0.0209623  66.684  < 2e-16 ***
    # BiomaPampa      -0.1256759  0.0268164  -4.687 2.78e-06 ***
    # poly(temp, 2)1   7.1035195  0.2079550  34.159  < 2e-16 ***
    # poly(temp, 2)2  -7.2900687  0.2629908 -27.720  < 2e-16 ***
    # UR               0.0302810  0.0008029  37.717  < 2e-16 ***
    # ---
    # Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    # Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    #             (Intr) BmTrns BimPmp p(,2)1 p(,2)2
    # BiomaTrnstn -0.586                            
    # BiomaPampa  -0.199  0.352                     
    # ply(tmp,2)1 -0.208  0.267  0.312              
    # ply(tmp,2)2 -0.191  0.085 -0.175 -0.039       
    # UR          -0.746  0.709  0.188  0.230  0.316
    # optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
    # Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
    #  - Rescale variables?
```

Second I try glmmADMB:

```
m.laden.2 <- glmmadmb(ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp,2) + UR + (1 | formigueiro), data = DataBase, family = "poisson", link = "log")
summary(m.laden.2)
# Call:
# glmmadmb(formula = ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp, 2) + UR + (1 | 
#     formigueiro), data = DataBase, family = "poisson", link = "log")

# AIC: 12033.9 

# Coefficients:
#                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)      1.52390    0.26923    5.66  1.5e-08 ***
# BiomaTransition  0.23967    0.08878    2.70   0.0069 ** 
# BiomaPampa       0.09680    0.05198    1.86   0.0626 .  
# poly(temp, 2)1  -0.38754    0.55678   -0.70   0.4864    
# poly(temp, 2)2  -1.16028    0.39608   -2.93   0.0034 ** 
# UR               0.01560    0.00261    5.97  2.4e-09 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# Number of observations: total=526, formigueiro=5 
# Random effect variance(s):
# Group=formigueiro
#             Variance StdDev
# (Intercept)  0.07497 0.2738
```

Despite the between different statistical packages and estimations, the models are completely different significance levels in the case of `Biome` variable. My question is,
where is any other approach that can be used to compare the results and choose a final model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even results from simple models like `ladenant ~ (1 | formigueiro)` are not similar ... glmmadmb actually errors out. But looking at the range of counts suggest Poisson may not be a great fit. Try using negative binomial (`glmer.nb` & `family = "nbinom"` in `glmmadmb`)

Comment: okay just tried .. quick look at coefficients . `glmer.nb(ladenant ~ Bioma +  poly(temp,2) + scale(UR) + (1 | formigueiro), data = DataBase)` and `glmmadmb(ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp,2) + scale(UR) + (1 | formigueiro), data = DataBase, family = "nbinom")` are the same. Not inspected the fit in any other way.

Comment: Thank you very much @user20650!! Better results using negative binomial and similar results of the model. Problem solved!

Comment: If the problem is solved you are encouraged to write up an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a little bit carried away. **tl;dr** as pointed out in comments, it's hard to get `glmmADMB` to work with a Poisson model, but a model with overdispersion (e.g. negative binomial) is clearly a lot better. Furthermore, you should probably incorporate some aspect of random slopes in the model ...

Packages (`colorblindr` is optional):

```r
library(lme4)
library(glmmADMB)
library(glmmTMB)
library(broom.mixed)
library(tidyverse) ## ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, purrr ...
library(colorblindr) ## remotes::install_github("clauswilke/colorblindr")
theme_set(theme_bw())
```

Get data: standardize input variables so we can easily make a sensible coefficient plot

```r
## read.csv doesn't work for me out of the box, locale/encoding issues
myds <- readr::read_csv("my_glmm_dataset.csv") %>%
  mutate(across(formigueiro, as.factor),
         across(c(UR, temp), ~ drop(scale(.))))
```

Formulas and models:

```r
form <- ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp,2) + UR + (1 | formigueiro)
## random slopes, all independent (also tried with correlations (| instead
## of ||), but fails)
form_x <- ladenant ~ Bioma + poly(temp,2) + UR + (1 + UR + poly(temp,2) || formigueiro)

glmer_pois  <- glmer(form, data = myds, family = poisson(link = "log"))
## fails
glmmADMB_pois  <- try(glmmadmb(form, data = myds, family = "poisson")) 
## fails ("Parameters were estimated, but standard errors were not: 
## the most likely problem is that the curvature at MLE was zero or negative"
glmmTMB_pois  <- glmmTMB(form, data = myds, family = poisson)
glmer_nb2 <- glmer.nb(form, data = myds)
glmmADMB_nb2 <- glmmadmb(form, data = myds, family = "nbinom2")
glmmTMB_nb2 <- update(glmmTMB_pois, family = "nbinom2")
glmmTMB_nb1 <- update(glmmTMB_pois, family = "nbinom1")
glmmTMB_nb2ext <- update(glmmTMB_nb2, formula = form_x)
```

Put it all together:

```r
modList <- tibble::lst(glmer_pois, glmmTMB_pois, glmer_nb2, glmmADMB_nb2, glmmTMB_nb2,
                       glmmTMB_nb1, glmmTMB_nb2ext)

bbmle::AICtab(modList)

                  dAIC    df
glmmTMB_nb2ext     0.0 11
glmer_nb2         27.0 8 
glmmADMB_nb2      27.1 8 
glmmTMB_nb2       27.1 8 
glmmTMB_nb1       79.5 8 
glmmTMB_pois   16658.0 7 
glmer_pois     16658.0 7
```

The 'nb2' models are all OK, but the random-slopes model is considerably better.

Coefficient plots, including the fixed effects from all methods:

```r
tt <- (purrr::map_dfr(modList, tidy, effects = "fixed", conf.int = TRUE,
                      .id = "model") |>
  dplyr::filter(term != "(Intercept)") |>
  tidyr::separate(model, into = c("platform", "distrib"))
)
ggplot(tt, aes(y = term, x = estimate, xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high,
               colour = platform, shape = distrib)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.25)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, lty =2) +
  scale_colour_OkabeIto()
```

[image: coefficient plot]